# How to fix connection error while fetching API? Kept crashing whenever trying to authenticate

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am doing a project that includes different modules that can sign in with different department to take logical test, and training etc etc.
However the API of the database and test is fetching from a REST API.

Currently i am facing problem connecting to the API

"Security Policy" Error whenever i try to authenticate.

Hence, now i am trying to connect to a localhost to test what is the problem and i cannot connect too. 
I am beginning to wonder is it my code problem or connection problem.

Please help!

Things i already tried :

- Setting internet permission in the Manifest file
- Create a network_security_config.xml

This is my Connection API :

```
interface MyApi
{

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("admin/42/login")
suspend fun userLogin(
    @Field("adminId") empID: String,
    @Field("password") password: String
) : Response<AuthResponse>

companion object
{
    operator fun invoke() : MyApi
    {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://localhost:8090/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(MyApi::class.java)
    }
}
}
```

This is my error in RED :

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                            Process: com.example.quizbeta, PID: 6407
                            java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:8090
                            at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:248)
                            at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:166)
                            at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
                            at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
                            at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
                            at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
                            at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
                            at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
                            at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
                            at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
                            at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
                            at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
                            at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
                            at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
                            at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
                            at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
                            at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:254)
                            at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:200)
                            at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
                            Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 8090) from /127.0.0.1 (port 59329) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
                            at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:273)
                            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:188)
                            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:130)
                            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:129)
                            at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:356)
                            at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
                            at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
                            at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:357)
                            at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:616)
                            at okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform.connectSocket(AndroidPlatform.java:73)
                            at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:246)
                            at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:166) 
                            at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257) 
                            at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135) 
                            at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114) 
                            at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42) 
                            at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) 
                            at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) 
                            at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93) 
                            at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) 
                            at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) 
                            at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93) 
                            at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) 
                            at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126) 
                            at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) 
                            at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) 
                            at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:254) 
                            at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:200) 
                            at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32) 
                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
                            Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
                            at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:262)
                            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:188) 
                            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:130) 
                            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:129) 
                            at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:356) 
                            at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200) 
                            at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182) 
                            at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:357) 
                            at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:616) 
                            at okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform.connectSocket(AndroidPlatform.java:73) 
                            at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:246) 
                            at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:166) 
                            at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257) 
                            at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135) 
                            at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114) 
                            at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42) 
                            at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) 
                            at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) 
                            at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93) 
                            at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) 
                            at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) 
                            at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93) 
                            at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) 
                            at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126) 
                            at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) 
                            at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) 
                            at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:254) 
                            at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:200) 
                            at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32) 
                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
                            Process 6407 terminated.
```

Answer (score 2):

> **FOR SECURITY POLICY ISSUE**

There is a policy allowing only HTTPS requests as clearText support disabled in android P.

create `network_security_config.xml` in xml folder inside res.
eg.

> res/xml/network_security_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">Your URL</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

now in

> manifest.xml

inside application tag
add flag

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```